# Nginx & https redirect

Tags: nginx, redirect, https

I tried to redirect http://www & http:// on https://, but I have a loop of redirection, do you know why ? When I only put server_name www.mywebsite.lol it's ok for https redirect...

I tried

```
server {
    server_name     mywebsite.lol;
    rewrite ^(.*)   https://mywebsite.lol$1 permanent;
}
```

and

```
server {
    server_name     mywebsite.lol;
    return          301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
}
```

And my full: configuration

```
server {
# Port
listen 80;

# Hostname
server_name mywebsite.lol;

# Logs (acces et erreurs)
access_log /var/log/nginx/mywebsite.lol.access.log;
error_log /var/log/nginx/mywebsite.lol.error.log;

# Repertoire
root /home/mywebsite/www;

# Fichier a executer par defaut (en ordre)
index index.html index.php;

pagespeed off;

# Needs to exist and be writable by nginx.  Use tmpfs for best performance.
pagespeed FileCachePath /var/lightpics_ngx_pagespeed_cache;

# Ensure requests for pagespeed optimized resources go to the pagespeed handler
# and no extraneous headers get set.
location ~ "\.pagespeed\.([a-z]\.)?[a-z]{2}\.[^.]{10}\.[^.]+" {
  add_header "" "";
}
location ~ "^/pagespeed_static/" { }
location ~ "^/ngx_pagespeed_beacon$" { }
pagespeed DisableFilters remove_comments;

#Expire Header
location ~* ^.+\.(ogg|ogv|svg|svgz|eot|otf|woff|mp4|ttf|rss|atom|jpg|jpeg|gif|png|ico|zip|tgz|gz|rar|bz2|doc|xls|exe|ppt|tar|mid|midi|wav|bmp|rtf)$ {
access_log off; log_not_found off; expires max;
}

location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
}

# pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server listening on the php-fpm socket
location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files $uri =404;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include fastcgi_params;

}

# Refuse accès httaccess
location ~ /\. {
    deny all;
}
```

}

Comment: What does the HTTPS server block look like?

Comment: I only have that in my file.lol. I use https thanks to cloudflare, I don't have certificate

Comment: Well, there's your problem.  You don't have any configuration that would actually serve content.

Comment: Are you sure ? When I remove https and add www. I have welcome to nginx blahblahblah

Comment: Yes, based on the information you've provided, I'm sure.

Comment: Can you send me a configuration to try please ?

Comment: You should focus on getting your site working correctly before sticking cloudflare in the mix....

Comment: I edited my first message. Work without https...

Comment: You don't appear to have any redirects at all. Just a parking page. And certainly no CloudFlare.

Comment: Note that blind redirect from http to https can be dangerous: you should not redirect http to http for anything that transmits credentials because the credentials will then be sent in clear without the user realizing it. So in the case if a Web page, it may be ok but for api calls made by users it is a big no no. Better send a reply to ' try https ' and make sure the user fixes his code to use https.

Answer (score 1):

The proper way to do a Nginx redirect is with HTTP 301, not a rewrite. See [here](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/tutorials/config_pitfalls/#taxing-rewrites).

As far as your server setup goes, see mine below. I define the server name on port 80, then redirect to HTTPS on port 443. Everything (SSL settings, root, index, etc...) is applied under this HTTPS server block.

```
server {
        listen 80 default_server;                       #Listen on IPv4
        listen [::]:80;                                 #Listen on IPv6
        server_name loganmarchione.com;
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;           #Redirect HTTP to HTTPS
}

server {
        listen 443 ssl spdy;                            #Listen on IPv4
        listen [::]:443 ssl spdy;                       #Listen on IPv6

        ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/unified2.crt;
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/my-private-decrypted.key;

        ...
```

Comment: I concur, this is how I have it configured pretty much the same way on a production site. The only difference is I have separate log files for each server.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting the redirect loop because the same 'server' directive is answering requests for both http (port 80) and https (port 443)

You want to have separate 'server' blocks for http vs https -  the http block should only redirect to https, whereas the https block should include your main config, ie 'root' & etc.

```
server {
  listen 80;
  server_name mywebsite.lol;
  rewrite ^(.*) https://mywebsite.lol$1 permanent;
}

server {
  listen 0.0.0.0:443 ssl;
  server_name mywebsite.lol;

  ssl_certificate      /etc/pki/tls/certs/mywebsite.lol.crt;
  ssl_certificate_key  /etc/pki/tls/certs/mywebsite.lol.key;

  # Repertoire
  root /home/mywebsite/www;

  ...

}
```